# Where do custom menus get constructed?

Tags: menus, search

I've created a simple menu in wp-admin>appearance>menus called main-nav. Works fine.

However, I'd like to add a custom element to the end of the menu... a search box like the search box in the apple.com menu bar. I can't work out where the  menus get constructed in code. where can I can add this... any ideas?

(I'm using the starkers theme)

EDIT

Thanks to tnorthcutt and hakre for pointing me in the right direction. The solution was to put this code in with the other 'add_filter' stuff in my theme's functions.php

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','search_box_function');
function search_box_function ($nav){
return $nav."<li class='menu-header-search'><form action='http://example.com/' id='searchform' method='get'><input type='text' name='s' id='s' placeholder='Search'></form></li>";
}
```

**UPDATE**

@tnorthcutt's solution is great for when you have just one menu on your screen, but if you add second menu it appends the search box to that menu too. How would you target just one menu? i've registered my menu's like so:

```
register_nav_menus( array(
  'primary' => __( 'Primary Navigation', 'twentyten' ),
  'secondary'=>__('Secondary Menu', 'twentyten' ),

 ) );
```

..and the secondary one gets shown like this:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'secondary' ) );
```

Comment: *@cannyboy* - since you've already marked the question as accepted, please put your "update" in a new question ... otherwise it probably won't get answered.

Comment: ok, i've done that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','search_box_function');
function search_box_function {
search box code goes here
}
```

For reference, check out Bill Erickson's [excellent tutorial](http://www.billerickson.net/genesis-wordpress-nav-menu-content/) on accomplishing this with the Genesis framework.

Comment: Thanks... where would that code go?

Comment: *@cannyboy* please try in your themes function.php.

Comment: this is great for just one menu, but how would i target specific menus? See my updated question.

Comment: There is version of that hook for targeting specific menus, it is called like `wp_nav_menu_{$menu->slug}_items`. Replace `{$menu->slug}` with slug of menu you want to target.

Comment: d'you mean this should go in the add_filter? when I change it to `add_filter('wp_nav_menu_primary_items','search_box_function');` I get no result.

Comment: Sorry, I kinda missed details (I use similar names so had mistaken one for another). This seems to be not a slug of location (which you use to register), but slug of menu that you create in admin interface, `Menu Name` field.